# String enclosed inside double quotes(") causes error with json.loads()

Tags: json, python-3.x

I see a weird behavior with double quotes with `json.loads()`. In the code given below x prints fine.

I want to understand reason for error when I print the value of y.
Why is 'a' printed inside single quotes when its actually inside double quotes.

```
import json

x = '[["a"]]'
y = "[['b']]"

print(json.loads(x))
print(json.loads(y))
```

**Output**

```
[['a']]  
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

Comment: please ignore (```) in the code, after struggling to format for half an hour i could not fix it.

Comment: Fixed the question for you. Please double check, if i didn't mess your output.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the formatting :)

Answer (score 1):

The JSON specification does not allow you to use single quotes for strings as explained here:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp

Comment: There is a Flask based REST API which takes a nested list as input. e.g
**[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]**

I pass this value as 
**{"test_data": "[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]"}**.

I read this value as request.json (Flask). I then try to convert it as list by using json.loads() but I get the error that I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Finally fixed it by replacing the single quotes with double quotes and then applying json.loads() but still wondering about the error.